# how to access a decorator Admin::ExampleDecorator in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1, draper

I have used draper gem to generate the decorator and I have crated a decorators. I have used namespacing inside decorator folder, and I tried to access the that decorator in specific controller with decorates_assigned.

For example
    my folder structure is decorators/admin/example_decorator.rb

And I have added the following line in controller:

```
decorates_assigned :example
```

and in action I have written

```
def edit
  @example = Admin::ExampleDecorator.new(Example.last)
end
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Could not infer a source for Admin::ExampleDecorator.
```

I am not understanding why this error is coming.

How namespaces are works in Decorator?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about your question, but since you are using `decorated_assigned :example` you are creating a helper method. See the [Draper readme](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/tree/v1.3.0#when-to-decorate-objects).

You won't need to call the decorator explicitely.

```
def edit
  @example = Example.last
end
```

This means in your view you will call `example` instead of `@example` to get the decorated version. This will call your helper method and returns the decorated version.